# Including JS file(s) only in a (some) JSF page(s) when HEAD tag is defined inside a template common to all pages

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-1.2

I'm working on a project where I'm using a template for all JSF pages. 
The `<head>` tag is defined in the template, so it's the same for all pages.

In this project JS is needed. I know JS files should be imported in the `<head>` but doing that for all JS files required by the project would be inefficient because every script would be included in every page.

I would like to know if there is a smart way to load a JS file(s) only for a(some) specific page(s) considering also that I'm using JSF 1.2 so it's not possible for me to solve this problem using `<h:outputScript>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JSP or Facelets as view technology? Since you explicitly said "template" I assume Facelets. But JSP is much more common in JSF 1.x. Just asking to be sure.

Comment: I'm using JSP as view technology, and a [third-party tag library named Jenia](http://www.jenia.org) for templating through the '<jt:includeMainView id="mVC">' and '<jt:mainViewContent id="mVC">' tag in the template and the specific pages respectively.

Comment: It's not possible by JSP, but by Facelets. I am not familiar with Jenia, but it look like that it could be the solution.

Comment: I'm currently not using Facelets, anyway, I would like to know what  solution you had in mind, because it could be a reason to reintroduce Faceles in the project. Thanks

Comment: With Facelets, you'd just use `<ui:insert>` inside `<head>` of master template and use `<ui:define>` in the template client to insert the `<script>` there. Migrating JSP to Facelets is not necessarily a trivial job, it takes a lot of time if you have a lot of pages. Jenia also won't work on Facelets.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, your reply is very useful!